# Enhanced C++ comments in VS Code: problem with mixed Doxygen and native features

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, comments, doxygen

C/C++ for Visual Studio Code extension v1.1.3 and VS Code v1.52.0 provide tooltip window with function and data member description when hovering above their identifiers, if they have comments. It's a combination of mixed Doxygen and native features. I'm looking for a link to documentation describing these features. The official website at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp has no information on this subject. I would like to get an explanation of behavior in cases like these:

**Example 1** (data member or local variable)

```
int n;  // number of widgets
```

works as expected, producing `number of widgets` description, but the Doxygen version:

```
int n;  ///< number of widgets
```

produces malformed description `/< number of widgets`.

**Example 2** (function member)

```
// f does nothing
void f();
```

produces `f does nothing` description, but this form:

```
void f(); // f does nothing
```

doesn't produce any description.

Comment: From what I understand this is a problem of VS-code tooltips and not a doxygen problem.

Comment: Doxygen as 3rd party tool is not involved here, I think. It looks like reimplementation of some Doxygen features,  but I'm looking for a description what works and in what context. Regular C++ comments are also rendered in tooltip, but only under some conditions. There is no documentation for that.